# Send a message to remote PC via Powershell

Tags: powershell

The script shuts down all PCs in certain OUs, if they are online longer than 2 days.
I want this script to send a message to the PC before it shuts the PC down.

```
function Get-LastBootUpTime {            
param (
    $ComputerName
)
    $OperatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName               
    [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)            
}

$Days = -0
$ShutdownDate = (Get-Date).adddays($days)

$ComputerList = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
$A = Get-Date

Add-Content C:\Scripts\Shutdown\Report\shutdown.txt "`nDatum:" $A

$ComputerList | foreach {
    $Bootup = Get-LastBootUpTime -ComputerName $_

    Write-Output "$_ last booted: $Bootup" | tee -Append C:\Scripts\Shutdown\Report\shutdown.txt

    if ($ShutdownDate -gt $Bootup) {

        Write-Output "Rebooting Computer: $_" | tee -Append C:\Scripts\Shutdown\Report\shutdown.txt
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "No need to reboot: $_" | tee -Append C:\Scripts\Shutdown\Report\shutdown.txt
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how... Anybody has an idea?

Comment: I've you're using Windows 10 you can use the UWP framework to write a toast-message (I've implemented this at the company for which I work), these can be sent remotely to a Windows 10 machine : the message can even include multiple images.

Comment: We're currently trying to use Windows 10 in our company, but there are still many Windows 7 active, so I can't rely on this method. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I update my post answering your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Send-NetMessage](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-NetMessage-Net-Send-0459d235) script, or do something yourself with [MSG](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490796.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command

Comment: already tried the Send-NetMessage, but it didn't work (maybe I did something wrong :/)

Comment: Wel Send-NetMessage was the only thing I tried yet, I didn't find any solution which I could use in the script

Comment: I advice send the message to all users 5 minutes in advance (in a separate script) to enable users from logout safely.

Comment: @M.Hassan how do I do that? I tried a seperate script, but even with a seperate script I would to now which PC is going to turn off and which won't. Sending a message to the guys who aren't in 'danger' would be kinda useless.

Comment: TechNet isn't available any more :/

Answer (score 0):

Msg.exe is used for sending a message to terminal server users,and it's send from the terminal server itself.

On the machine that you cannot send a message modify its registry.

Use regedit to navigate to:

```
 HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server
```

Change the following value:

```
 Name : AllowRemoteRPC
 Type : REG_DWORD
 Value : 1
```

Or use the following powershell script

```
 $RegKey ="HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server"
 Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name AllowRemoteRPC 
 Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name AllowRemoteRPC -Value 1
 Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name AllowRemoteRPC
```

I advice to send a message in advance e.g. 5 minutes to users who are about to be shutdown.

The users to send a message :

```
    $msgScript = {
        $Days = -2
        $ShutdownDate = (Get-Date).adddays($days)

        $ComputerList = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=X,OU=X,DC=X,DC=X' ` -Filter '*' | Select -EXP Name
        $A = Get-Date

        $ComputerList | foreach {
            $Bootup = Get-LastBootUpTime -ComputerName $_    

            if ($ShutdownDate -gt $Bootup) {
               #send-msg
                Send-NetMessage "Shutdown start in 5 minutes.  Please log off." -Computername $_ -Seconds 0 -VerboseMsg -Wait

            }     
        }
    }
```

You can automate the task of sending the message and task of shutdown with a delay, example:

```
  #load the scripts, note the dot at start of line
  . .\Get-LastBootUpTime.ps1
  . .\Send-NetMessage.ps1

  $DELAYTIME=5 #minutes
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $SendMessage
  # wait 5 minutes
  Set-WaitTime $DELAYTIME  #you can implement it

  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ShutDown
```

**Update:**

In order to avoid the error message saying that Get-LastBootUpTime and Send-NetMessage aren't cmdlets, you shoule load these functions.
 To load these functions run the following code:

```
 . the_path_to\Get-LastBootUpTime
 . the path_to\Send-NetMessage
```

If these scripts are in the current folder

```
. .\Get-LastBootUpTime.ps1
. .\Send-NetMessage.ps1
```

note the dot at the start of line

Comment: Sounds good, and I tried it,but it just didn't work... I tried to add a few things and change somethings bu it doesn't even run when I tell powershell to run it. It just is a text for powershell. But it's a start, thank you

Comment: I got it to run (I just deleted the $msgscript = {}). Now it says that Get-LastBootUpTime and Send-NetMessage aren't cmdlets, which is not true because Get-LastBootUptime works fine in my other already finished script.

Comment: I got it now, i needed to enable the functions of Get-LastBootUptime and Send-NetMessage in the script. Now it works completely thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to work around any restrictions with `msg.exe` is to use PowerShell to run it using WinRM.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -SriptBlock {
    msg 1 /server:localhost "Rebooting $ENV:COMPUTERNAME"
}
```

This requires WinRM to be enabled on all computers.

See [MS Docs - Installation and configuration for Windows Remote Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management)